# computed fields on different tabbedpanels

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a tabbedpanel with 3 tabs.

On the first one are the fields;

LastName
FirstName
MI

On the second tab is a TaxPayer field which is computed by concatenating the above.

LastName + ", " + FirstName + " " + MI

Just doing the coding for the last name (Make sure that works before I make it pretty.) I'm doing an onChange event in the LastName field;

```
var LastName = XSP.getElementById("#{id:TLast}").value;
XSP.getElementById("#{id:Taxpayer}").innerHTML = LastName
```

The result isn't being sent to the computed TaxPayer field on the second tab.

Looking at the source HTML generated while in the first tab, I see no mention of the second tab so my guess is that when I try to change something on the second tab, it's just not there.

Is there a way to do this?

[Edit] - I found another way to do this. Rather than "Pushing" the value to my FInvoiceDoc from each of the fields, I just went to the computed field on the second panel and made the value of it;

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="TaxpayerDsp"
         style="color:rgb(0,0,0)">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
  var lastName = currentDocument.getValue("TLast");
  var firstName = currentDocument.getValue("TFirst");
  var mI = currentDocument.getValue("TMI");
  var taxPayer = lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + mI;
  taxPayer.trim()}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

Now I don't have to worry about document refreshes at all. I also included a hidden field which will update the back-end document;

```
<xp:inputText 
  id="TaxPayerDoc"
  value="#{FInvoiceDoc.TaxPayer}" 
  styleClass="xspHiddenFields">
</xp:inputText>
```

Where xspHiddenFields is in my CCS Style sheet as;

```
.xspHiddenFields {color:rgb(255,0,0);width:98.0px}
```

Then I make a  function call from my TLast, TFirst, and TMI fields to update this value;

```
function updateTaxpayer() {
// called from the onChange events of TLast, TFirst, and TMI.
var TLast = XSP.getElementById("#{id:TLast}").value;
var TFirst = XSP.getElementById("#{id:TFirst}").value;
var TMI = XSP.getElementById("#{id:TMI}").value;
var TaxPayer = TLast + ", " + TFirst + " " + TMI;
XSP.getElementById("#{id:TaxPayerDoc}").value = TaxPayer;
}
```

This may have been what the answers below meant in the first place. I may have mis-interpreted it. Anyway, it's made me aware of the joys of currentDocument. Now I just need to get that server-side xPage debug toolbar working....

Comment: As an alternative, it might be worth using Hidden Input (xp:inputHidden) outside the tabbed table, binding it to #{FInvoiceDoc.TaxPayer} and updating that in the onChange via a partial refresh. Just be aware that onChange may not fire in Internet Explorer, but you can use onBlur. Then bind the Computed Text (xp:text) to FInvoiceDoc rather than computing the value dynamically. Unless you have connectivity problems or heavy latency, the partial refresh will be quick and easier to code. You can use "Process Data Without Validation" if you have validation elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saving the information then you should use the document.getValue method instead of get elementById
Or 
You could save the information as a scoped variable and then work with the scoped variables instead of getting the elementById.

Comment: Patrick is right. XPages apps are better the closer you get to the MVC pattern, so get data always from the Model (aka the data) rather than the view (aka the UI controls). Very different from classic Notes where Model = View (mostly)

Comment: And use the Extlib tabs

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with the following statement; FInvoiceDoc.replaceItemValue("Taxpayer",currentDocument.getValue("TLast"))

Comment: Copied that code into Patrick's answer, so we can have the answer in the answer instead of in a comment....

Comment: Not sure what MVC is (but I'll look it up whenever that stage-coach gets that copy of "Mastering xPages" to me.) Seems to me that every time I involve the back-end, unpleasant things happen. Typically for refreshes and I loose field focus. In this example I've set it to "No Update" which seems to work fine but when I bring an existing doc up, it does some kind of a refresh and again, I loose my focus. I would imagine that if we have to go running to the server for every little bit of information, network traffic would go up. Then again, I don't understand the model yet.